# How does the Wheel.java program and its use of arrays work?

Tags: java, arrays, count

I'm having a difficult time understanding the wheel counter program.  In general, I understand what the program does but I don't understand the fundamental specifics of how it gets there.  I'm hoping someone can explain it to me.

Essentially, what I don't understand is how the 
`int[] letterCount = new int [26];` is storing the count of the characters in the last portion of the second method (I believe that section is called a method (lines 20-30) - I'm still trying to get the java parts down).  I also don't understand how `letterCount = (lett - 'A');` creates a count of each letter and how that ties into the `int[] letterCount = new int [26];`

The way I understand it is that it's going through each of the characters and deciding "Okay, this is an 'A' so (65-65)=0 and that's also an 'A' because it's letterCount [0].

But why is `letterCount [0]` an 'A' and how is it counting the 'A's if it's only storing `letterCount [0]`, `letterCount[1]`, letterCount[2], etc.  It seems to me the number in the array somehow represents a letter of the alphabet but not a count.  I'm hoping someone can tie this together for me.

The entire code is:

```
    1: class Wheel {
    2:  public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    3:      String phrase[] = {
    4:          "A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE",
    5:          "DON'T EAT YELLOW SNOW",
    6:          "JUST DO IT",
    7:          "EVERY GOOO BOY DOES FINE",
    8:          "I WANT MY MTV",
    9:          "HOW 'BOUT THEM COWBOYS",
    10:             "PLAY IT AGAIN, SAM",
    11:             "FROSTY THE SNOWMAN",
    12:             "ONE MORE FOR THE ROAD",
    13:             "HOME FIELD ADVANTAGE",
    14:             "VALENTINE'S DAY MASSACRE",
    15:             "GROVER CLEVELAND OHIO",
    16:             "WONDERFUL WORLD OF DISNEY",
    17:             "COAL MINER 'S DAIJGHTER",
    18:             "WILL IT PLAY IN PEORIA"
    19:         };
    20:         int[] lettercount = new int[26];
    21:         for (int count = 0; count < phrase.length; count ++} {
    22:         String current = phrase[count];
    23:             char[] letters = current.tOCharArray();
    24:             for (int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++){
    25:                 char lett = letters[count2];
    26:                 if ( (lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z') ) {
    27:                     letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
    28:                 }
    29:             }
    30:             }       
    31:         for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
    32:             System.out.print(count + ": " +
    33:                 letterCount[count - 'A'] +
    34:                 "\t");
    35:         }
    36:         System.out.println();
    37: }
    38:}
```

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: The code you pasted will not compile (just by looking at it).  You end array access operator [ with }, and close a for loop with } instead of ).  I suggest you try to compile the code first and make it work.  Also to get which letter it is you often subtract the character value with 'A', so 'A'-'A' is 0, 'B'-'A' is 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`letterCount[lett - 'A']` - it is one member of `letterCount` array.

This array have 26 members, at start all of them is 0.

`lett` is char. When you do `(char - char)` you receive `int`.

So, for example `lett` is 'S' now. Code of 'S' is 83, and the code of 'A' is 65. So we have now `letterCount[18]` is responsible for 'S' counting.

At start it was 0. After `letterCount[18]++;` it become 1, etc.

In this part:

```
for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
    System.out.print(count + ": " + letterCount[count - 'A'] + "\t");
}
```

when `count` become 'S', we again have `letterCount['S' - 'A']` (18!), so `letterCount` DOES NOT store letters, it stores "difference" between each letter and 'A'.

There is formatted code:

```
class Wheel {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String phrase[] = {
                "A STITCH IN TIME SAVES NINE",
                "DON'T EAT YELLOW SNOW",
                "JUST DO IT",
                "EVERY GOOO BOY DOES FINE",
                "I WANT MY MTV",
                "HOW 'BOUT THEM COWBOYS",
                "PLAY IT AGAIN, SAM",
                "FROSTY THE SNOWMAN",
                "ONE MORE FOR THE ROAD",
                "HOME FIELD ADVANTAGE",
                "VALENTINE'S DAY MASSACRE",
                "GROVER CLEVELAND OHIO",
                "WONDERFUL WORLD OF DISNEY",
                "COAL MINER 'S DAIJGHTER",
                "WILL IT PLAY IN PEORIA"
        };

        int[] letterCount = new int[26];

        for (int count = 0; count < phrase.length; count++) {
            String current = phrase[count];
            char[] letters = current.toCharArray();
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < letters.length; count2++) {
                char lett = letters[count2];
                if ((lett >= 'A') & (lett <= 'Z')) {
                    letterCount[lett - 'A']++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (char count = 'A'; count <= 'Z'; count++) {
            System.out.print(count + ": " + letterCount[count - 'A'] + "\t");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavlo!  But what still confuses me is does letterCount[18] equal the amount of times S occurs or does letterCount[18] mean that it equals the number representation of 'S' on the scale of A-Z?  I believe letterCount[0] = 'A', no?

Comment: No, there is the output of the program: A: 22    B: 3      C: 5      D: 12    E: 28    F: 6      G: 5      H: 8     I: 19      J: 2       K: 0      L: 13     M: 10    N: 19    O: 28   P: 3            Q: 0     R: 13     S: 15     T: 19     U: 3     V: 7      W: 9     X: 0      Y: 10     Z: 0